# Select only one row with max field with One-Many Relationship Table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have 2 Table, the `Chapter` Table have many row with manga_id is id of `Manga` Table

Manga Table

```
ID | NAME      | SLUG 
1    One Piece   one-piece
2    Naruto      naruto
3    Gintama     gintama
```

Chapter Table

```
MANGA_ID | NAME    | SLUG             | CREATED_AT
1          Chap 1    One-Piece-Chap-1   2016/01/01
1          Chap 2    One-Piece-Chap-2   2016/01/02
1          Chap 3    One-Piece-Chap-3   2016/01/03
2          Chap 1    Naruto-Chap-1      2016/01/02
2          Chap 2    Naruto-Chap-2      2016/01/03
2          Chap 3    Naruto-Chap-3      2016/01/04
3          Chap 1    Gintama-Chap-1     2016/01/07
3          Chap 4    Gintama-Chap-4     2016/01/09
```

And I looking for select only 1 manga have 1 chapter with order by  `created_at` DESC

Example table i looking for:

```
Manga_ID | Manga_NAME | NAME    | SLUG             | CREATED_AT
3          Gintama      Chap 4    Gintama-Chap-4     2016/01/09
2          Naruto       Chap 3    Naruto-Chap-3      2016/01/04
1          One Piece    Chap 3    One-Piece-Chap-3   2016/01/03
```

I really appreciate anyone answer in this topic and save my day

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html

Comment: You want to select the last chapter of every manga ?

Comment: Yes and order by created_at with active = 1 :D thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SELECT
     mt.id as MANGA_ID,
     mt.NAME as MANGA_NAME,
     ct.NAME,
     ct.SLUG,
     MAX(ct.CREATED_AT) as CREATED_AT
 FROM
     Chapter ct
 LEFT JOIN
     Manga mt
 ON (mt.id = ct.MANGA_ID)
 GROUP BY
     ct.MANGA_ID`

This should do the trick.

Comment: Hi Vasil, can you help me add Where Clause mt.active = 1 and ct.active = 1, when i add this close before group by name and slug is not Newest but date is true. This is result:

Manga_ID | Manga_NAME | NAME    | SLUG             | CREATED_AT
3          Gintama      Chap 1    Gintama-Chap-1     2016/01/09
2          Naruto       Chap 1    Naruto-Chap-1      2016/01/04
1          One Piece    Chap 1  One-Piece-Chap-1   2016/01/03

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT t1.MANGA_ID, t2.NAME AS Manga_NAME,t1.NAME,t1.slug,t1.CREATED_AT
FROM Chapter t1
INNER JOIN Manga t2 ON t1.MANGA_ID = t2.ID
WHERE t1.CREATED_AT = (SELECT MAX(CREATED_AT) from Chapter t3 where t3.MANGA_ID = t1.MANGA_ID)
```

Comment: can you please add index on `MANGA_ID` and `CREATED_AT` in chapter table